# Android Facebook SDK 3.17.2: "Unsupported get request."

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am using facebook sdk for android version 3.17.2. I haveing same unusual errors when I try to use share dialog. Share dialog appears, but after that it crushs.

```
private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
    return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity)mContext)
            .setName("facebook")
            .setDescription("facebook")
            .setLink("http://facebook.com");
}


FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

log errror:

```
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344): Exception during service
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:102)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:135)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:218)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:183)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.JsonResponseHandler.a(JsonResponseHandler.java:34)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.b(ApiResponseHandler.java:78)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:53)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:312)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:142)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:98)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:228)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:436)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:198)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:20)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:361)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:58)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:280)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:57)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(23344):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: I found same problem and don't know how to solve this